# Postgres Performance: Static row length?

Tags: performance, postgresql

Mysql behaves in a special (presumably more performant) manner [when a table has no variable-width columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/static-format.html)

Does postgres have similar behavior?  Does adding a single variable-width column to a table make any major difference?

Comment: Be nice if that link had a usable test. Do you have a test in mind that you would think of using to test this out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The general advice given in the [postgres docs (read the tip)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/datatype-character.html) is that variable length fields often perform better because it results in less data so the table fits in less disk blocks and takes up less space in cache memory. Modern CPU's are so much faster then the memory and disks that the overhead of variable length field is worth the reduction in IO.

Notice that postgresql stores NULL values in a bitmap at the beginning of the row and omits the field if the value is NULL. So any nullable column has basically a variable width. The way postgresql stores it data ([Database page layout](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/storage-page-layout.html)) suggests that retrieving the last column would be slower then the first column. But this will probably only have a noticable impact if you have many columns and the data was mostly in cache to start with. Otherwise the disk io will be the dominant factor.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, no it doesn't

Check this link out for general talk about datatypes my conclusion from this read is whatever special behavior mysql exhibits, postgresql doesn't which to me is good. http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2010/03/02/charx-vs-varcharx-vs-varchar-vs-text/

Comment: Unless I missed something in those tests the tests are actually performed with fixed length data. So when testing say a varchar(50) the data allways has 50 chars. Which means these tests are the worst possible scenario for the varchar columns as they doo not benefit from their capability to store less data for shorter values.

Answer (score 0):

> *presumably more performant*

I would never ever believe any "performance myth" unless I test it with my own set of data and with a workload that is typical for my application.

If you need to know if *your* workload is fast enough on DBMS X with *your* data, don't look at anything else than the numbers you obtain from a realistic benchmark in your environment with hardware that matches production.

Any other approach can be replaced by staring at good crystal ball

Comment: Believe me, I'm the first guy to utter the "profile, profile, profile" mantra.  If I do pursue this at all, I will test amply.  Regardless, the question stands: some databases have specific, special behavior for this case, and I'd like to know if postgres is ones of them.  This is an useful thing to know, independent of any specific workload.

Comment: @Frank: the question is: does it matter? And once the TOAST threshold for a column value is exceeded, things become even less comparable.

Comment: "Go measure" is neither valid nor constructive. -1 and vote to close.